# access bitbucket webhook trigger payload in jenkins multibranch job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks, payload

I have a jenkins multibranch job and want to be able to view / print the bitbucket webhook trigger payload value as a string in my jenkinsfile. So I can see why the build was triggered, if it was triggered because of a commit, PR merge, etc...

I've been researching alot online, normal non-multibranch jobs have the parameterized build setting option, but multibranch jobs have the paramaters option. my bitbucket webhook triggers the build correctly.

I think at this point I might need to add something to my multibranch job to set the payload as a string variable I can access and print to console in my multibranch job's jenkinsfile.

Thx

Comment: I don't think you are able to do that. A webhook does not trigger your build, it triggers a handler that does something (most probably branch/tag scanning of the repo) and potentially puts your job into the queue. When the job starts, the webhook payload is long gone. It does not really matter in the end; in multibranch you either build a branch, a tag or a pull request. I don't think it makes any difference what was the actual reason from the webhook.

Comment: Agree with @raspy: if for some reasons you don't want to build, you should configure the webhook to not fire. All the other information is either irrelevant, or you can fish it from bitbucket.

Comment: @MaratC & raspy thank you for the advice. I was trying to do this because I want my jenkisnfile to do X if the build is for a PR being merged into develop branch, do Y if the build is a pr getting merged into master, and do Z for everything else. Not sure how to do this,  I cant find a param or env var with this info, maybe I can make a bitbucket api call and get this info? Or a git command? Or have multiple different jenkinsJobs, like one that gets triggered only on PR merges

Comment: @raspy see my comment above

Comment: You may want to look at different bitbucket plugins for Jenkins  to include this info for you, or you may want to issue an API call with `curl ... | jq ...`. We work with github and we use both approaches, so I can't speak for bitbucket, sorry.